# Android studio gives me a lot of hidden methods warning

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i am working on an Android project and i am getting a lot of access hidden methods warning and i don't know what i am doing wrong. My application works fine so i really don't know what to do to delete these warnings. Plese help me i really don't know what should i do. I am a beginner in Android so i really have no idea.

```
    W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;-><clinit>()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->EMPTY_STACK_TRACE:[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTATION_PERMISSION:Ljava/lang/RuntimePermission; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->lock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->daemon:Z (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->threadLocals:Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->inheritableThreadLocals:Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;-><init>(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/String;IZ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stillborn:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->group:Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;->addUnstarted()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->auditSubclass(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread$1;-><init>(Ljava/lang/Class;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->exit()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;->threadTerminated(Ljava/lang/Thread;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->target:Ljava/lang/Runnable; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->inheritedAccessControlContext:Ljava/security/AccessControlContext; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blocker:Lsun/nio/ch/Interruptible; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->uncaughtExceptionHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;->systemThreadGroup:Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->getNativeTid()I (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->getUncaughtExceptionPreHandler()Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->uncaughtExceptionPreHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;J)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/security/AccessControlContext;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init(Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;Ljava/lang/Runnable;Ljava/lang/String;JLjava/security/AccessControlContext;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->name:Ljava/lang/String; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;->addUnstarted()V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->init2(Ljava/lang/Thread;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->contextClassLoader:Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal;->createInheritedMap(Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap;)Ljava/lang/ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->interrupt0()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->isCCLOverridden(Ljava/lang/Class;)Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread$Caches;->subclassAuditsQueue:Ljava/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread$Caches;->subclassAudits:Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->processQueue(Ljava/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue;Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nativeCreate(Ljava/lang/Thread;JZ)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nativeGetStatus(Z)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadID()J (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->threadSeqNumber:J (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nextThreadNum()I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->threadInitNumber:I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->threadInitNumber:I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->processQueue(Ljava/lang/ref/ReferenceQueue;Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->setNativeName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->setPriority0(I)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->setUncaughtExceptionPreHandler(Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler;)V (greylist-max-o,core-platform-api, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->sleep(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->sleep(Ljava/lang/Object;JI)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockedOn(Lsun/nio/ch/Interruptible;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blocker:Lsun/nio/ch/Interruptible; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->dispatchUncaughtException(Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->tid:J (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->priority:I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/VMStack;->getThreadStackTrace(Ljava/lang/Thread;)[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Llibcore/util/EmptyArray;->STACK_TRACE_ELEMENT:[Ljava/lang/StackTraceElement; (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nativeGetStatus(Z)I (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->uncaughtExceptionHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->uncaughtExceptionHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blockerLock:Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->blocker:Lsun/nio/ch/Interruptible; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->interrupt0()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->interrupt0()V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->nativePeer:J (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->setNativeName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/RuntimeHooks;->getThreadPrioritySetter()Ldalvik/system/ThreadPrioritySetter; (blacklist,core-platform-api, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->setSystemDaemon(Z)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->systemDaemon:Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->uncaughtExceptionHandler:Ljava/lang/Thread$UncaughtExceptionHandler; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;->add(Ljava/lang/Thread;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->stackSize:J (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/Thread;->nativeCreate(Ljava/lang/Thread;JZ)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ljava/lang/Thread;->started:Z (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ljava/lang/ThreadGroup;->threadStartFailed(Ljava/lang/Thread;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;-><init>(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)V (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->definingContext:Ljava/lang/ClassLoader; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->splitPaths(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/util/List; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->nativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden field Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->systemNativeLibraryDirectories:Ljava/util/List; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->getAllNativeLibraryDirectories()Ljava/util/List; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;-><init>(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;-><init>(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Z)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;-><init>(Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/File;Z)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->splitDexPath(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/util/List; (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
W/rackingmypantr: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->concat(Ljava/lang/Class;[Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)[Ljava/lang/Object; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->getAllNativeLibraryDirectories()Ljava/util/List; (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->lambda$initByteBufferDexPath$0(Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)Z (blacklist, linking, denied)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexPathList;->loadDexFile(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$Element;)Ldalvik/system/DexFile; (greylist, linking, allowed)
    Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/DexFile;-><init>(Ljava/io/File;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;[Ldalvik/system/DexPathList$Element;)V (greylist-max-o, linking, denied)
```

Comment: "My application works fine" what more do you expect?

Comment: I wanted to understand this warnings

Comment: why do you assume they are warnings? Nowhere in that entire block I find the word 'warning'

Comment: The "W/" string at the beginning of the log it should mean Warning if i am not wrong

Comment: You should provide more details like when this warning came i.e. As soon as app get open, or performing specific task.

Comment: This warnings come as soon as app get open, at the really beginning. But I dont'know what causes them

Comment: did you understand what this warnings are? I got the same behavior...hateful

Comment: Yes, If I understood these warnings should mean that you are using some functions that in future could be deprecated. But I am not sure 100% so check it

Answer (score 4):

`Accessing hidden field` warning means that your app is using some restricted non-SDK interfaces.

> Starting in Android 9 (API level 28), the platform restricts which non-SDK interfaces your app can use. These restrictions apply whenever an app references a non-SDK interface or attempts to obtain its handle using reflection or JNI. These restrictions were put in place to help improve the user and developer experience and reduce the risks of crashes for users and emergency rollouts for developers.

This [document](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-compatibility/restrictions-non-sdk-interfaces) provides a comprehensive explanation on this topic and provides guidance on how to resolve these issues:

> While you can currently use some non-SDK interfaces (depending on your app's target API level), using any non-SDK method or field always carries a high risk of breaking your app. If your app relies on non-SDK interfaces, you should begin planning a migration to SDK interfaces or other alternatives. If you cannot find an alternative to using a non-SDK interface for a feature in your app, you should request a new public API.